# Where is the version number of dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies

I asked a similar question before regarding the way to inherit dependency version number through parent pom, and I got that part. But now I saw a similar POM and am clueless where the version numbers of these dependencies are provided. As you can see, all the dependencies have no version numbers specified and the parent POM doesn't provide these either.

Please help understand how this works. Thanks a lot.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source
Copyright 2013, Red Hat, Inc. and/or its affiliates, and individual
contributors by the @authors tag. See the copyright.txt in the
distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.quickstarts</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-quickstarts-parent</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>wildfly-greeter</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>WildFly Quickstarts: Greeter</name>
<description>WildFly Quickstarts: Greeter</description>

<url>http://wildfly.org</url>
<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
    </license>
</licenses>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Define the version of JBoss' Java EE 7 APIs we want to import.
           Any dependencies from org.jboss.spec will have their version defined by this
           BOM -->
        <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 7 APIs including
           a Bill of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or
           a collection) of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct
           versions of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-7.0 stack (you can
           read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs). You can actually
           use this stack with any version of WildFly that implements Java EE 7, not
           just WildFly 8! -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope 
       as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- Set the name of the war, used as the context root when the app 
       is deployed -->
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- WildFly plugin to deploy war -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: use mvn dependency:tree to see how includes are managed. Also, have a look at the mvn versions plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In maven the dependencies version can be managed in `<dependencyManagement>` tag.

In your case the versions are managed with the following

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
   <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
   <version>${version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0}</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

In the above tag the scope is import that means the pom will be imported so the dependencies version are maintained in org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-7.0 artifact. It's mentioned in the comments above the tag.

REF:[jboss-javaee-7.0-1.0.1.Final.pom](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/spec/jboss-javaee-7.0/1.0.1.Final/jboss-javaee-7.0-1.0.1.Final.pom)

Comment: But this version number is only for org.jboss.spec. I am talking about many other dependencies, javax.enterprise for example.